# How to check that a DLL or executable was compiled with security cookies enabled?

Tags: c#, security

I am trying to figure out a way to check if a specific DLL / EXE file has security cookies enabled. I might say that I don't have the source code, and that I wasn't the one that compiled it. I have only the compiled DLL's and the executable.

I know that there is a way to achieve it by disassembling the file and check if the cookie was pushed to the stack before calling a function, and also check that before returning from a function a verification of that cookie is made. But, this method is really inconvenient and messy.

Does anyone know an alternative method for checking it?

Note : the code was written in C#/.NET, and I'm running Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: What is your primary intention to check for buffer overrun?

Comment: I just want to make sure that the program is secured, so it has no buffer overrun vulnerability.

Answer (score 2):

You can guarantee that your C# code was not written with `/GS` because C# does not support `/GS`, that is a feature of the C++ compiler, the C# compiler does not have that option.

If you use the [`fixed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21(VS.80).aspx) statement in C# it is your responsibility to check for buffer overflows. Managed code will not let you have a buffer overflow.

So I guess you could say all "safe" code behaves like you had `/GS` enabled and all pointers used in "[unsafe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8(v=vs.80).aspx)" code blocks behaves like it was not enabled.

Finding if a program was compiled with the compiler flag [`/unsafe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ct597kb0.aspx) is a different enough topic I would recommend asking a new question for that.

Comment: Your'e right about the /GS flag. Thanks.
I've edited my question.

Comment: My answer still stands. C# does not use secure cookies for unsafe code but does use other stack corruption means for normal managed code.